# Remove specific row of TableLayoutPanel using dynamically created button of each row

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

So I am making a function that will populate the TableLayoutPanel from FileDialog Result then make a delete button for each row using a loop. Here's the code

```
Private PathtoFile1 As New List(Of String)  'this will contain all the selected file in the dialogwindow
Private rowLineDrawing As Integer = 0
Private selectedfilecountLineDrawing As Integer


Public Function AttachFileLineDrawing(TLP As TableLayoutPanel)
    Dim dr = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog

    If (dr = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        selectedfilecountLineDrawing = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count


        For Each FileName In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Try
                Console.WriteLine(FileName.ToString)
                PathtoFile1.Add(FileName.ToString)
            Catch SecEx As Security.SecurityException
                MessageBox.Show("Security error. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" &
               "Error message: " & SecEx.Message & "\n\n" &
               "Details (send to Support):\n\n" & SecEx.StackTrace)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Could Not Load the image - probably permissions-related.
                MessageBox.Show(("Cannot display the image: " & FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("\"c)) &
                ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " + "it may be corrupt." _
                & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & "Reported error: " & ex.Message))
            End Try
        Next

        'MAKE SOMETHING HERE TO DISPLAY THE SELECTED ITEMS IN THE TABLELAYOUTPANEL OF THE SUBMIT PROGRESS 
        TLP.Controls.Clear()
        TLP.RowCount = 0
        rowLineDrawing = 0
        For Each Path In PathtoFile1

            Dim filepath As New Label
            filepath.Text = Path
            filepath.Width = Val(360)

            'this button is for previewing the file
            Dim btnPreview As New Button

            AddHandler btnPreview.Click,
                Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
                    Dim btn = CType(s, Button)
                    MsgBox("This is Preview")

                End Sub

            'This button is for removing rows in the tablelayoutpanel
            Dim btnRmv As New Button



            Dim StringToIndex As String = Path  'THIS CATCHES EVERY PATH IN THE LOOP AND STORE IT TO THE VARIABLE WHICH THEN BE USED AS A COMPARABLE PARAMETER FOR THE INDEX SEARCH
            Dim index = PathtoFile1.IndexOf(Path)
            AddHandler btnRmv.Click,
                Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
                    Dim btn = CType(s, Button)
                    MsgBox(index)
                    PathtoFile1.RemoveAt(index) 'THIS LINE OF CODE REMOVE THE SPECIFIC ITEM IN THE LIST USING THE  BTNRMV CLICK

                    'MAKE SOMETHING HERE TO REMOVE THE ROW IN THE TABLELAYOUTAPANEL 

                End Sub



            TLP.SuspendLayout()
            TLP.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20))
            TLP.Controls.Add(filepath, 0, rowLineDrawing)
            TLP.Controls.Add(btnPreview, 1, rowLineDrawing)
            TLP.Controls.Add(btnRmv, 2, rowLineDrawing)
            TLP.ResumeLayout()
            rowLineDrawing -= -1

        Next
    End If
End Function
```

So I am trying to remove the row in the TableLayoutPanel together with the dynamic control. My approach is removing the selected item in the list and I achieved it properly but can't remove the row in the TableLayoutPanel. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT

I have tried to use the provided module above but got this error

[image]

And got this error

[image]

Comment: There's no inherent way to insert and remove from anywhere but the end of the table. I would suggest that you write a method that takes a `TableLayoutPanel` and row index as arguments, removes the controls in that row, moves the controls in all other rows up, then removes the last row.  You could write it as an extension method and then call it on the control itself. In fact, I'll do that and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method that will enable you to remove any row from a `TableLayoutPanel` by index:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module TableLayoutPanelExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Sub RemoveRowAt(source As TableLayoutPanel, index As Integer)
        If index >= source.RowCount Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(NameOf(index),
                                                  index,
                                                  "The row index must be less than the number of rows in the TableLayoutPanel control.")
        End If

        'Remove the controls in the specified row.
        For columnIndex = 0 To source.ColumnCount - 1
            Dim child = source.GetControlFromPosition(columnIndex, index)

            If child IsNot Nothing Then
                child.Dispose()
            End If
        Next

        'Move controls below the specified row up.
        For rowIndex = index + 1 To source.RowCount - 1
            For columnIndex = 0 To source.ColumnCount - 1
                Dim child = source.GetControlFromPosition(columnIndex, rowIndex)

                If child IsNot Nothing Then
                    source.SetCellPosition(child, New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(columnIndex, rowIndex - 1))
                End If
            Next
        Next

        'Remove the last row.
        source.RowCount -= 1
    End Sub

End Module
```

I tested that on 3 column by 4 row `TableLayoutPanel` containing a `Label` in each cell executing the following code twice:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TableLayoutPanel1.RemoveRowAt(1)
End Sub
```

The result was as expected, i.e. removing the second-from-top row each time.  You may need to fiddle a bit more depending on what you want to happen row heights.  I had the row heights set to equal percentages so the remaining rows grew proportionally to fill the space.  If you want something different, you can add code accordingly.  Note that you could create an almost identical method for removing columns.

Comment: Hello pal, please take a look to my feedback below. By the way thanks for the module